# WP Как выводить комментарии по выбраному фильтру?

Tags: wordpress, get

Есть пример вот такого [сайта](https://www.productreview.com.au/listings/mitsubishi-bronte-srk-zra-series?rating=5) На этой странице есть фильтр по рейтингу комментариев оставленного по продукту.
[image: Рейтинг по продукту]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое реализовать на `WordPress` *Я не понимаю логики. Как они сделали, что добавляя в get параметр URL адресса им отфильтровывает страницу с комментариями которых были оценины в рейтинг 5... Вот есть вывод комментариев, а как контролировать, что б если в URL `?rating=5` то пробрасывть страницу с выводом только комментариев по рейтингу 5 ?

```
<div id="comments" class="company-rewiew-list">
    <?php
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'type' => 'comment',
        'reverse_top_level' => false,
        'reverse_children' => false, 
        'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'number' => $per_page,
        'cpage' => $page,
    )); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну в зависимости от того, как и где они хранят рейтинг, могут быть разные подходы. Если это значение из мета коммента, то это можно подставить в [get_comments()](https://wp-kama.com/function/get_comments), если рейтинг хранится в отдельной табличке, то SQL запрос.

Comment: *В моём случаи значения комментариев храниться в отдельной таблице WP. Можно подробнее, как преходя по ссылке с GET параметром, как в текущем примере `/mitsubishi-bronte-srk-zra-series?rating=5`  мне вытащить туже страницу, но что бы в `wp_list_comments($arg, $comments)` моего шаблона падал уже другой отсортированый массив из комментариев.

Comment: Получаете гет параметр посредством `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'rating', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);` либо как-то иначе, на основе этого делаете SQL запрос в Вашу таблицу с выбором нужного количества комментариев с необходимым рейтингом, подставляете ID комментов в функцию [get_comments()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_comments#comment__in) как массив в параметр `comment__in` и передаете вторым параметром в [wp_list_comments()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_comments#example_34869)

Comment: Спасибо, это похоже на реальный план)